# VS2012: 'rassapi.h' - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ras

One project, that we are trying to port to VS2012 includes `<rassapi.h>` which is not part of SDK 8.0. Well, I found out that `<mprapi.h>` contains some defines, but some functions like `RasAdminGetUserAccountServer` and `RasAdminUserSetInfo` are still missing. Do you know how to workaround this?

Comment: are you using .Net framework 4.5 ?

Comment: check this Link you will get some information http://corelibrary.sourceforge.net/doxygen/Mprapi_8h.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this is function similar to ur Method **RasAdminUserSetInfo**

```
DWORD APIENTRY MprAdminUserSetInfo  (   IN const WCHAR *    lpszServer,
IN const WCHAR *    lpszUser,
IN DWORD    dwLevel,
IN const LPBYTE     lpbBuffer    
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Also I found this [fuction comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I cannot find `RasAdminGetUserAccountServer` :(

Comment: can u check this. I am not good at C, http://search.cpan.org/~lmasara/Win32-MprApi-0.02/MprApi.pm

Comment: check this Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374594(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, according to this [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it seems to be `MprAdminGetPDCServer`